# how do I make a div and table headers fixed when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page that contains a navbar fixed on top, then comes up my main div, inside I have a header content div and a table, I need the header content div and the table headers to be fixed just bellow the nav bar which is fixed on top. I have also a navbar fixed on bottom.

Here is some code of what I have:

```
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="position: fixed;"> ... </nav>

         <br><br><br><br>

         <div id="mainDiv">

                <div id="HeaderContentDiv"> ... </div>

                <table id="myTable">

                       <thead>

                            <tr>
                                 <td> Code </td>
                                 <td> Product  </td>
                                 <td> Description</td>
                                 <td> Quantity </td>
                                 <td> Actions  </td>
                           </tr>

                      </thead>

                      <tbody> ... <tbody>

                </table>

         </div>


  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="position: fixed;"> </div>

</body>
```

I need the header content div and the table headers to be fixed at the top of the page, bellow the top nav bar.

Here is a screenshot of my page: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaV2k.png)

Well, thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It may be better just to make the table itself scrollable (eg: place inside div with `overflow: auto` and maximum height).

Comment: I have put the table element inside the div (set div to overflow:auto and 100% height), made no difference at all on what I have.

Comment: You will need to limit the height of the div (sorry, what I meant was the `max-height` property). You will want to set the `max-height` to some value that makes sense (possibly 300-400 pixels for most screen sizes)

Comment: Now it worked to make the header content div fixed, but how about to make the table headers fixed as well?

Comment: In this case, instead of applying `overflow: auto` and fixed height to the container div, you will need to apply it to the `tbody` element.

Comment: it seems your tbody solution works, but only when you set position: fixed or position: absolute on tbody as well, other than that makes no difference.The issue is that making position fixed or absolute ruins the mobile application design, the tbody part compacts itself on screen width, and I need it stretches a little beyond to better display information, only the header stays normal.

Comment: Yes, applying `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` will remove the element from the normal flow (giving it 0-height). So, we will also need to set a minimum height on the parent element (the table).

Comment: I guess you meant the position attributte will make the element fit to screen width, right? And I believe you wanted to say to set min-width on tbody, that way it will occupy a specific width despite the fact it is fixed. Well I have tried that and on smaller screens, even when shrinking the browser's window, it still gets messy in a way only seeing to understand, so I will use the div solution, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: you closed your '<span>' tag before '<table>' tag .if there is any missing there please fix that first